# How can I use structured files in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, file, ipad

I am developing for iPhone/iPad.

I already know how to read/write text files from/to the documents folder and now I need to write structured files, e.g. let's say I have a class in my application that is called A which contains an integer i and integer j and an instance of another class B, let's call it b, now I want to write A to a file in a way that I can read it next time to another object from type A without the need to read a text file and parse its contents (to avoid time cost).

so anyone to help me?

PS: if you used Pascal before, what I need is exactly something like its binary files.

Answer (score 2):

You can do archive and unarchive. Your class need to conform to NSCoding protocol

```
MapView *myMapView;   // Assume this exists

NSString *archivePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Map.archive"];

result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myMapView 
                        toFile:archivePath];
```

[Archive and Unarchive](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000949-BABGBHCA). [NSCoding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)